# EventTriggers on an Image

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal

I have a set of `Image`s in a GridView, and the images are not able to load instantly when the page is opened. So, to create a smoother transition, I am trying to use an `EventTrigger` in the `Image` to animate the opacity from 0 to 1 when the image loads, like so:

```
<GridView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Border Background="{ThemeResource ButtonBackground}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MaxWidth="300" MinWidth="200">
            <Image Source="{Binding SmallUri}" Stretch="UniformToFill"
                Opacity="0" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding Author.Name}">
                <Image.Triggers>
                     <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.ImageOpened">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="00:00:00.25" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                     </EventTrigger>
                </Image.Triggers>
            </Image>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridView.ItemTemplate>
```

But whenever the page attempts to load, it crashes with the error:

```
Failed to assign to property 'Windows.UI.Xaml.EventTrigger.RoutedEvent'
```

Why does this not work? It also fails if I change the RoutedEvent property to Loaded, FrameworkElement.Loaded, Image.Loaded, or any other value I could think of. I would like a solution that does not involve having to write a custom control / codebehind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But whenever the page attempts to load, it crashes with the error "Failed to assign to property 'Windows.UI.Xaml.EventTrigger.RoutedEvent'." Why does this not work?

As @Clemens said, problem is in Windows Runtime XAML, the default behavior for event triggers and the only event that can be used to invoke an EventTrigger is FrameworkElement.Loaded.

I'm writing this answer here to call another problem of your code, as you said:

> It also fails if I change the RoutedEvent property to Loaded, FrameworkElement.Loaded, Image.Loaded

This is because you didn't specify the `Storyboard.TargetName` in your `DoubleAnimation`, it will throw the exception when it runs. To solve this problem, you will need to give a name to your `Image` in the `DataTemplate` and modify your storyboard like this:

```
<Image x:Name="myImage" Source="{Binding SmallUri}" Stretch="UniformToFill">
    <Image.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="00:00:5" Storyboard.TargetName="myImage" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Image.Triggers>
</Image>
```

Comment: Does `<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.Loaded">` actually work? Documentation says "don't set the RoutedEvent attribut". OP also states that "it also fails if I change the RoutedEvent property to Loaded".

Comment: @Clemens, yes you're right, whether `RoutedEvent="Image.Loaded"` is set here or not, this storyboard will be triggered when this framework is loaded, I reproduced OP's issue and found when change the RoutedEvent property to Loaded, the exception is: "Evaluation of methods on COM objects is not supported in this context. ", by giving a name and force the storyboard target this name will solve this issue.

Comment: @Clemens, it works, and it means, in UWP, you can either set `Loaded` event to `RoutedEvent`, or you can leave this `RoutedEvent`,  they behavior the same.

Answer (score 0):

From the *Remarks* section on the [EventTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br242390) page on MSDN:

> If you do choose to use [**Triggers**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.triggers), in Windows Runtime XAML, the default
>   behavior for event triggers and the only event that can be used to
>   invoke an **EventTrigger** is **FrameworkElement.Loaded**. Because that's both
>   the default and the only enabled behavior, don't set the **RoutedEvent**
>   attribute. Just use the XAML `<EventTrigger>`. For more info, see
>   [**Triggers**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.triggers).

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late for answering the question but for those who will be having the same issue.
you can use this XAML code:

```
<Image x:Name="TumbImage" Opacity="0" ...>
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="ImageOpened">
      <media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource ImageOpacityStoryBoard}" ControlStoryboardOption="Play"/>
    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

The Sample storyboard I used here:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="ImageOpacityStoryBoard">
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TumbImage"
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" 
    From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.33" />
</Storyboard>
```

and the XML namespaces used:

```
xmlns:i="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
xmlns:media="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Media"
```